# Integral of $108x^8\sqrt{324x^4+36x^2+1}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Please help me find it ..  I know there is some trick to be used here but i am not able to proceed further $$\int_{0}^{1}108x^8\sqrt{324x^4+36x^2+1}dx$$
I know it may be silly but i am not able to complete these kinds

Answer (score 7):

$$324x^4+36x^2+1=(18x^2+1)^2$$

Now for real $y,\sqrt{y^2}=|y|$  and for $y\ge0,|y|=+y$